# matching just one (regex with quantifier and grouping in python)

Tags: regex

regex with quantifier and grouping in python

```
p = re.compile('[29]{1}')
p.match('29')
```

why does 29 match p? i thought i explicitly said it's [29] (2 or 9) with {1} quantifier.
Shouldn't it be JUST 2 OR 9? Or does it match the first group and not care about the rest
thanks!

Comment: FYI, there's no "grouping" in your regex.  Groups are created by using parentheses (a.k.a. round brackets).  `[29]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is matching because it matches the sub-string '2'. The way regex works is that it returns true is there exists *any substring* inside the string that matches. The regex you are using would match '46657467562374746', because it contains a '2'. If you need the whole thing to match from beginning to end, you need to use anchors:

```
p = re.compile('^[29]{1}$')
p.match('29')
```

The hat (^) represents the beginning of the string and the dollar ($) represents the end of the string. So now this will only match if the *whole* sting is a single 2 or a single 9, instead of just *containing* a 2 or 9.